# accessing internet via 3g dongle: pb with port 443

Tags: networking, pi-2, internet

I'm trying to access the internet using a 3G dongle on my pi (raspberry pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie) and encountering the following pb:

I can ping google.com **successfully**, I even downloaded some pictures from S3.

```
PING google.com (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hi.link (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.610 ms
```

But I can't ping 8.8.8.8:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
```

when I try git pull on my repo, I get:

```
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection refused
```

Here are the result of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c6:2a:6e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:830418 (810.9 KiB)  TX bytes:680649 (664.6 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:2c:80:13:92:63  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3d2:b0ae:25df:f0c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63112 (61.6 KiB)  TX bytes:23512 (22.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:839739 (820.0 KiB)  TX bytes:839739 (820.0 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:ae:4c:f8:33:93  
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e07d:62f:5613:c360/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51999 errors:0 dropped:1300 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4449 errors:0 dropped:164 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3463464 (3.3 MiB)  TX bytes:896138 (875.1 KiB)
```

my 3G dongle is **eth1**

```
pi@pi-1:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth1
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

I guess something is not configured properly with the 3G dongle, but don't know what.

I know very little about networking, so please tell me if you need more code and I will provide.

Comment: So it turns out that my dongle was a "fake one". It was a refurbished orange dongle that has been "unlocked" in a quick and dirty fashion, and that in fact does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You were not able to ping Google:

```
PING google.com (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hi.link (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.610 ms
```

`192.168.1.1` (actually every IP address starting with `192.168.`) is always a private IP address, commonly used in local LANs as provided by home WLAN routers, etc.  The connection you have claims that its network gateway is Google since

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
```

says that `192.168.1.1` is the IP of the next router (either something inside your 3G dongle or — less likely — your 3G network provider).

Comment: I'm having that problem. Do you have any real solution (besides pointing out that he's not connected to internet?). It would be nice. Thanks!